# Which textbooks for random (Brownian) motion derivations?

Tags: resource-recommendations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, randomness

I am a chemist currently trying to dive in to details of random motions. I have been studying Einstein-Smoluchowski treatment, and want to learn further (Fokker-Plank's equation and Langevin treatment etc). Although I am comfortable with mathematics some of the textbooks I came across include lot of symbols I am not aware of, and hence it gets overwhelming. Could someone please recommend me textbooks which provide detailed conceptual and mathematical treatments, assuming I am not aware of all the symbols or denotations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggestion on good stochastic processes book for self-teaching](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301579/)